# CUDAFunctionLoad doesn't work -> Target system specification

Tags: cudalink

W`hen I try to execute simple kernels with CUDAFunctionLoad I get this message:

> "Target system specification \"TargetSystemID\" -> \
>   !(\"Windows-x86-64\") is not available for !(\"NVIDIA CUDA \
>   Compiler\") installation"

What does it mean?

I have Mathematica 11.0.0 with a GeForceGTX960M; Visual Studio 2015 Community(update3) installed; `CUDAQ` returns `True`, `CUDACCompilers[]` returns `{}`.

Comment: I think the issue is that CUDA versions earlier than 8.0 are not compatible with Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Did you try CUDa 8.0 with Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Have you had any success?

Comment: Yes! It was a compatibility problem. I solved the problem turning to VS2013 and installing GPU drivers compatible with the latest release of CUDA paclet in Mathematica. Thanks you all guys. @Eisbär